# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`. & Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I speak little engilsh,sorry first.

I have searched some similar questions, but not help.
Can't figure out what happen by myself, it almost spend me 1 hours.

I start my project with latest yeoman & generator-react-webpack.

Some error always exist.In the browser console.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to`Router`.
Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes
```

here is `index.js`.

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import IndexPage from './components/IndexPage';
import Pages from './components/Pages';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={IndexPage} />
        <Route path="/pages" component={Pages} />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('webapp'));
```

here is `Indexpage.js`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class IndexPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>1234</div>
        )
    }
}
```

and here is `pages.js`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class Pages extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>9876</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout if the filenames and import statements have the correct spelling.

pages.js should be **P**ages.js
Indexpage.js should be Index**P**age.js

Or change it in the import statements.. its case-sensitive.

The docs says you have to wrap your Routes with a main Router /

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>

      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>

    </Route>
  </Router>

  // this is the main App component
  const App = ({children}) => (
     <div id="main-layout">{children}</div>
  )
```

Comment: I have checked before.No problem here.I tried to render IndexPage component without Router, it's ok.Everything going on.BUT when I wrap the component into Router.OMG!

Comment: @sadmark check out my edits, I checked the docs for you, this should be the way to go

Comment: I AM SO STUPID!
I got the ploblem just now.
The reason is that I added some comments inside the router tag WITHOUT {}.

THANKS A LOT   : )

Answer (score 0):

Your pages.js has a wrong class name. Instead of also calling it as IndexPage, you want to call it as **Pages** like below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class Pages extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>9876</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad!
This is a mistake when I copied my code,but it's right in my computer.
Checked serval times before.